# Sharepoint format date automatically change

Tags: list, datetime, sharepoint

I made list on sharepoint with the column date, the format datetime was yyyy-MM-dd. After that I edited the date then the format changed automatically to dd/MM/yyyy. how do i change it back to yyyy-mm-dd?

I already tried to change the region but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you apply any JSON column formatting on this column? Which regional/language settings you are using currently?

Comment: No, I didn't apply any JSON code. My regional is English (england)

Comment: Can you try using English (US) language ant US time zone once and see it it works?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint online, you can use column formatting to change the date format. Here is the Json:

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "span",
  "txtContent": "=replace(getYear([$CustomeDate]) + '/' + getMonth([$CustomeDate])+ '/' + getDate([$CustomeDate]),'//','')"
}
```

[image]
[image]